# Does using a Github Webhook with an IP address instead of a URL work?

Tags: jenkins, github, continuous-integration

I'm trying to set up the integration between Jenkins and Github.

A publicly exposed IP address has been setup.
The 'hooks' addresses under [meta](https://api.github.com/meta) have been whitelisted.
Firewall exceptions have also been added.

Under the 'Payload URL' section on Github, it's been set up as:
http://xx.xxx.x.xxx/github-webhook/

http://xx.xxx.x.xxx:8080/github-webhook/ has also been tried.

But I'm getting the error: 'We couldn’t deliver this payload: failed to connect'

I can confirm that we can see incoming traffic from one of the Github webhook IP addresses, so it seems to make the connection to the server.

Please also note, that when the Payload URL was set up using the link generated by NGROK, it worked fine.

What am I missing in this setup?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using in-house wifi router. If so, you can set up port forwarding on your router of which method is slightly different for each vendor of the router.
That is, you have to set up "port forwarding" feature on the home router to forward the traffic from Github to your Jenkins http port number (the default port number for Jenkins is 8080)
How to set up port forwarding on the home router? On windows, open cmd and execute ipconfig command to find the IP address of your router. You then need to log in the router using the IP address on your web browser. Once you log in (the password is on the back of the router or user's manual or you can google it to find the preset password for your router, then you'll find the link to set up port forwarding provided by the router vendor. Well, way more trouble than just using ngrok.